# Android ConstraintSet animation via xml vs programatically

Tags: android, animation, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I am working on a complex UI using ConstraintLayout where there are multiple views/menus (containing buttons, textviews, widgets etc) animate from bottom/offscreen on different click events. Each menu has different constraints and animation. Now there are multiple issues i am facing right now.

1. By default all menus will be hidden/offscreen. So its difficult to design/update layout because every time i need to work on a menu first i must update its constraint and constraints of all views attached to it to show in LayoutEditor. Which is troublesome
2. Animation Issue. All these views animate from bottom of screen. I found two ways to animate views using ConstraintLayout.

First is to copy layout file as it is and just change constraints to animate

```
val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
onstraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout)
val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet2.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_alt) 
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
val constraint = if (changed) constraintSet1 else constraintSet2
constraint.applyTo(constraintLayout)
```

The issue with this approach is that i need to duplicate xml files. As I have 10 views that need to animate from bottom then i must create 10 layout files. Plus there is also performance issue as compared to programatically as animation starts with a little delay.

Other approach is to do all these animations by setting constraints programatically.

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.connect(R.id.myButton, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 
      ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
set.connect(R.id.myButton, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 
      ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
set.constrainWidth(R.id.myButton, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
set.applyTo(myLayout);
```

Which is also difficult to set for 20 to 30 views and menus. But i find this approach much effective as i dont need to duplicate xml files plus i find it better performance wise because in this case animation starts in millisecond without any delay.

Which is the best approach to implement in my case where i have more than 30 views to maintain and animate in a single flat constraint layout file?